# how to configure jquery ajax with asp.net?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
url: "SaveAudiVideo.aspx/SaveData",
data: JSON.stringify({title: 'value1' ,songPath: 'value2' }),
dataType: "json",
success: function(data) {
$('lbltxt').text(data.d);
},
error: function(result) {
alert("error");
}
});
```

This is the code I have tried. I have seen lot of examples in the net everything resembles the same, but it is not working for me. Is there any other thing to configure and include into my project before running this ajax script? like JSON(newtonsoft) asp.net ajax?

Comment: It would be nice if you show little code on cs file SaveData method. Also this link help you. http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Call-ASPNet-Page-Method-using-jQuery-AJAX-Example.aspx

Comment: so many things could go wrong with this if you didn't set all the blocks correct: is your SaveData method defined as static and [WebMethod], does your SaveData have the title and songPath parameters, does your json gets parsed correctly? In general: open firebug and check for javascript errors to have a bit more info on whats going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

**Firstly**

Add jquery link to your master page

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

**Secondly**

You are giving path like

```
SaveAudiVideo.aspx/SaveData
```

It seems that you are trying to access aspx page method. but if you don't configure your aspx like web api it won't work.

To make your .aspx page mathod like web api

**Try This**

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string SaveData(string title,string songPath)
{
    return title+" "+songPath;
}
```

There more info [here](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Call-ASPNet-Page-Method-using-jQuery-AJAX-Example.aspx)

here is another [example](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/using-web-api-with-aspnet-web-forms)  you can try this.